# Python basic loops

Tags: python, loops

I have a question. What is wrong with this loop?
I'm writing a number-guessing mini-game.
The problem is that when the user enters the correct number on the second or third  try, the loop still forces the user to 'try again' even though the correct number was entered but not the first time. The rule of the game is 4 chances to guess the other player's number

```
def do_action_to_guess(first_number: int, second_number: int):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 4:
        if first_number != second_number:
            counter += 1
            second_number = int(input('Try again'))
        elif first_number == second_number:
            print('That is correct number')
            break

    else:
        print('Out of chances')
    return counter
```

Comment: It works for me. Can you show how you call it and sample user input/output

Comment: Note that this allows 5 guesses, because you're not counting the guess before the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't run into the issue you're describing. One issue that does occur is that if you make the correct guess on the fourth guess, it claims you are incorrect and then runs out of chances. This is because on turn i you are actually checking the answer from turn i-1. Instead of using the `second_number` argument, you should just ask for the `second_number` at the beginning of the loop and then check the condition.

```
def do_action_to_guess(first_number: int):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 4:
        second_number = int(input('Guess the number'))
        
        if first_number != second_number:
            counter += 1
            print('Try again')
        elif first_number == second_number:
            print('That is correct number')
            break


    else:
        print('Out of chances')
    
    return counter
```

Answer (score 0):

According your code, the first step your loop will be with counter= 0,
the second step will be with `counter=1`,
the third ... `counter=2`,
the fourht ... `counter=1`.
You should change the limit from `counter=4` to `counter=3`.
Or you can start the counter from 1.